# Loop through divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, fadeout

I'm trying to get these divs to fadeout out when the arrow is clicked (like a very simple slideshow). I can make them fade out, one by one, like thus:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/x3buT/37/)

However, this won't let me

- Loop through (so start again when all are faded out)
- It won't work when another class is being clicked

Is there a jQuery method can loop through each `<li>` and fadeOut. If it is the last `li`, start the sequence again?

Comment: What do you mean with 'it won't work when another class is being clicked'? And for the other question: after each click check how many li's are still visible, if none then let them all fade in again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/x3buT/39/

Here I fade out the first slide, then move it to the end of the line and fade in the next

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slide:not(:first)').hide();
    //If you only need to change with the arrow, remove .slide from next line
    $('.slide,.arrow').click(function(){
        $('.slide').first().fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
            $(this).appendTo('.inner');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: +1. Judging from his initial solution, I would add li to $('.slide') making it $('.slide, li') to keep both the arrow and li click handler.

Comment: @DonBoots Right, but I think you mean `$('.slide, .arrow').click(...)`,that would make the slide change on click.

Comment: Thanks. Is .slides:not(:first) a css attribute, akin to nth-child(1) ?

Comment: @TomJulianHume Not really, take a loot at the [docs for the :first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/). It returns the first element on the list of matched elements, while css's nth-child can return multiple elements, all that are the first direct descendants of their parent

Comment: You've been really great, thank you. I must ask though, how come (:first) is in brackets? Why not $('slide:not:first')?

Comment: That's because of the [:not selector syntax](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) you have to use parenthesis to provide the selector that your elements should NOT match, in this case we use :first. So basically what this does is find all slides, then remove the ones that match `:first`, (only the first one), so we end up with all slides but the first